# Without using 'INTERSECT' , How to retrieve only the rows that exist in both tables?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am a beginner reading the book `Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes (Fifth Edition)` to learn SQL.

Here is an expmple SQL query from the book from **Chapter 14 - Combining Queries**.

My question regarding a note which says about other `UNION` type - `INTERSECT`

Firstly - see the Structure of Tables from this [Db Structure - Image](https://learning.oreilly.com/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:9780135182925/files/graphics/app01fig01.jpg)

Here is the Query

```
SELECT cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_state IN ('IL','IN','MI')
INTERSECT
SELECT cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_name = 'Fun4All'
ORDER BY cust_name, cust_contact;
```

In the note after this example, it says that

> INTERSECT can be used to retrieve only the rows that exist in both tables.

**And Below that line**

> **In practice, however, these UNION types are rarely used because the same results can be accomplished using joins.**

**So, How can I accomplish this using joins and not `INTERSECT`?
I tried doing all I learned but couldn't get the result.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically need an appropriate unique key (`PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY`), so that you can join by it safely. Assuming you have some `cust_id` column, you can join

```
SELECT c1.cust_name, c1.cust_contact, c1.cust_email
FROM Customers c1
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM Customers
    WHERE cust_name = 'Fun4All'
) as c2
ON c1.cust_id = c2.cust_id 
WHERE c1.cust_state IN ('IL','IN','MI')
ORDER BY cust_name, cust_contact;
```

Note however, that in your example it's even simpler

```
SELECT cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_state IN ('IL','IN','MI') AND cust_name = 'Fun4All'
ORDER BY cust_name, cust_contact;
```

Comment: `WHERE cust_state IN ('IL','IN','MI') OR cust_name = 'Fun4All'`

Comment: @wildplasser we're simulating `INTERSECT`, I believe

Comment: The question is unclear. The original fragment with UNION is equivalent to the OR in my comment. The rest of the question? What does INTERSECT have to do with it? Does the OP want EXISTS() ?

Comment: I know that my example is using `UNION` as taken from book. See.. Using `INTERSECT` will retrieve only the rows that exist in both tables. I want to do the same thing without using  `INTERSECT`. Just use the two queries in example as a base.

Comment: I just edited my question to clear the confusion. Sorry for the confusion I created @wildplasser

Comment: It would be very kind, if someone could help me in my revised question. Thanks.

Comment: @Rakesh Poddar My solution already solves your revised question. If you don't have `cust_id` column, then you should consider having one, because `cust_name` isn't unique enough to be joined on reliably. You can try to join on `cust_contact` or `cust_email` instead, if you believe that they are unique enough, and that they don't contain `NULL` values

Comment: `cust_id` is present in db. Please see the [Db Structure - Image](https://learning.oreilly.com/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:9780135182925/files/graphics/app01fig01.jpg). If possible, can you please write your query for MariaDB version? As.. the current one does not works. Thanks

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with MariaDB, so afraid I cannot. What are the errors anyway?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It said `Unknown column 'c2.cust_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Oh yeah, just do `JOIN (SELECT * FROM ...)` instead, it couldn't find the column `cust_id`, because we didn't select it

Comment: Would be glad if you would accept the answer

Comment: Now I think that my question was really not only easy (Which I even knew) but also somewhat silly. Actually I was little confused in the query but this got clear when I comapared it to Sets in Mathematics. It simply evalutes to `Choose only the row where cust_name = 'Fun4All' and he lives in ('IL','IN','MI')`.

Comment: Now.. this also helps me in making a workout for `MINUS` :)